# ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax error

Tags: java, sql

I'm creating an online voting system ,where all votes by all users are stored in a database. I want to avoid duplicates. For example, lets say user X votes B on question A. This information is added to the database. Then one week later, the same user X decides to vote C on the same question A. So instead of adding another entry into the database, the old entry should be updated with the new information. I tried using the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query, but I'm getting a rather weird syntax exception :

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "ON" at line 1, column 53.

Code:

```
public void castVote(int id, String username, String option) {

    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\MyDB;create=true;upgrade=true");
        String query = "INSERT INTO Votes (id, username, op) " + "VALUES (?,?,?) "
                + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + "id = ?, username = ?, op = ?";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, option);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}
```

I must say I'm rather new to SQL statement and databases, so maybe my query is wrong from the get go. But the exception is rather weird

Comment: The appropriate comment:  You cannot use generic MySQL syntax with Derby.  Install a MySQL driver if you want to use MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Derby doesn't have a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement

You should be able to use `MERGE`
documentation [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefsqljmerge.html).